# How to detect if a contructor is noexcept with a throwing destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits, exception-specification

The following code will fail to compile on most compilers:

```
#include <type_traits>

class Foo
{
    public:
    Foo() noexcept {}
    ~Foo() noexcept(false) {}
};

static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<Foo>);
```

CppReference also [states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible#Notes) that this is common in compiler implementations, but provides no alternative. How can I test if a constructor is noexcept without the destructor influencing the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [LWG issue 2116](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2116), linked from the cppreference page you linked, this is not a bug, but intended behavior.

As also mentioned in that issue, one can use the non-throwing placement-new, which only constructs, but doesn't destruct an object, to test the exception specification of only the constructor:

```
static_assert(noexcept(::new(std::nothrow) Foo()));
```

This requires including `<new>` for `std::nothrow`.

Here is a rough implementation of the trait:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct is_nothrow_default_constructible
: std::bool_constant<false> { };

template<class T>
struct is_nothrow_default_constructible<T,
    std::enable_if_t<noexcept(::new(std::nothrow) T())>>
: std::bool_constant<true> { };
```